# Search in .phtml files for text

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, twig

I'm looking for a way to search in a folder with `.phtml` files and 'scan' the files for words.

This what I have in my `.phtml` files (twig engine):

```
<span>{{ 'language'|trans }}</span>
<a href="#">{{ 'Settings'|trans }}</a>
```

I have multiple .phtml files with these translations in it.
 Now I would like to scan all the files and search for the strings before the `|trans` .

Is there a way to do this? And could you give me a tip how to begin with this? Because I have no clue how to start with this.

Comment: yes of course there is a way (several)

Comment: And could you give me a tip how to begin with this? Because I have no clue how to start with this.

Comment: Do you want to do this in php for some reason, or is this a one off fix?

Comment: I would like to do this with php because I know some php. But this is just for one time... I would like to save them in a database with some other options. So I don't want to insert manually in the database ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said there are more ways to do this. This is just one take on it, I'm not pretending this is the best way to do it (in fact, my preferred way would be totally different, including not using PHP).

Use `opendir()` to create a list of files to scan. On the [documentation page](http://www.php.net/opendir) some examples are shown that are quite useful for your purpose. Loop through the files and get their contents using, for example, `file_get_contents()`. Then use `preg_match_all()` on that content to find the strings you want. An example regex, based on the content in question, would be `/\{{2}\s*([^|]+)\|trans\s*\}{2}/i`.

Comment: Thanks, and how would you do this without php? What's your preference?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the regex. When I have for ex this: {% block title %}{{ 'Detail Hostess:'|trans }} {{ host.Name }}{% endblock %} . He will insert 'Detail Hostess:', that's correct. But he also inserted host.Name }}{% endblock %}

{% block content

Comment: A quick test on the example string you provided with my regex gives me just 'Detail Hostess:', nothing more. But what you provide as being inserted contains '{% block content', which is not in the example string. As I said, it's an example regex, meaning that you may need to tweak it. As for my preferred method, I would use command line tools such as find, grep and sed, to format the results to CSV, which can then easily be imported by your preferred MySQL admin tool.

Comment: Changed the regex to "/\{{\s*([^|}]+)\|trans\s*}}/i" and works perfectly now! Thanks!